# Change footnotes in a table

Tags: tables, footnotes, revtex

I have this `LaTeX` script:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{table}
\caption{
Caption}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
Column 1 & Column 2  \\
\colrule
100\footnote{footnote 1} & 200\footnote{footnote 2} \\ 
& 300\footnote{footnote 3} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The footnotes are labeled as a, b and c. I would like to use for one of them something different, for example to have them as a, b and *. How can I do this?

Comment: Technically, one can redefine `\thefootnote` or `\@thefnmark` to be anything.

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
Column 1 & Column 2  \\
\colrule
100\tabularnote[a]{footnote 1} & 200\tabularnote[b]{footnote 2} \\ 
& 300\tabularnote[*]{footnote 3} \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]